# I have an arraylist and its size is 1, but when i get at index 0, i get = java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    VideoTask videoTask =  new VideoTask(paccakModel, childPosition, video);
    videoTask.execute();

    ArrayList<VideoModelXml> test = videoTask.getVideoModelXmls();
    test.get(0);

   video.setVideoPath(test.get(0).getUrlVideo());
   video.start();
    return true;
}
```

I have an arraylist and its size is 1, but when i get at index 0, i get   =  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
can anybody tell me, what is going on?

Comment: Add your `VideoTask` implementation. your `getVideoModelXmls` return empty list

Comment: If you get the error, than your arraylist is not size 1. Check `videoTask.getVideoModelXmls()`, it probably doesn't do what you think it should do.

Comment: `... its size is 1 ...` No, its size is **0**.

Comment: i have checked it using debugger and its size is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your issue is `videoTask.getVideoModelXmls()` returns nothing. It should be empty. If you want to avoid the crash

```
ArrayList<VideoModelXml> test = videoTask.getVideoModelXmls();
if (test .size() > 0){
test.get(0);

   video.setVideoPath(test.get(0).getUrlVideo());
   video.start();
}
```

Which will avoid your crash.